# Find variable that is uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: correlation

I am given PMF of random variable X. P(X=0) = P(x=1) =0.5. Now there is another RV Y such that Y = XZ. I have to find Z independent of X such that X and Y are uncorrelated but not independent. My first intuition is that the PMF of Z should be 1/z^3. And Z can take values form 1 to n. This way each time it is multiplied with X, U gets reduced. So, even if X is increased to 1 U won't increase. 
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned both U and Y as RVs. I'll assume that they both refer to the same variable so U=XZ.

Note that Cov(U,X)=0
E(UX) - E(U)E(X)

Since Z and X are independent we have E(U) = E(XZ) = E(X).E(Z)

Substituting that in the equation above we get:

= E(X^2).E(Z) - E(Z).E(X)^2

=E(Z).(E(X^2) - E(X)^2)

=E(Z).var(X)

Now we know that var(X) is not 0. So just define Z such that E(Z) = 0.

That's pretty simple to do. Just define an RV symmetric around 0. So +-1 both with probability 0.5 and you get your Z.

Comment: I defined RV Z that takes value 1 with probability 1. And I guess that worked too. Thanks anyways

Comment: That way you'll get E(Z) = 1. Since var(X) ≠ 0, you won't get cov(u,x)=0

Comment: E(Z) = 1 and E(X) = 0.5 and E(U) = 0.5 and E(UX) = 0.25.  If I plug into equation E(UX) - E(X)E(U) = 0.25 - 0.5*0.5.